# CanJS/JavascriptMVC: How to store a view template in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, canjs, canjs-view

Is it possible to define a view template in a javascript variable, instead of a script tag or a file?

Something like this:

```
var template = "< h1 ><%= title %> < / h1 >"; 
var rendered = can.view.render(template, data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of research, because it isn't written in documentation, I found how to do it.
The trick is that you have to register your template with an id first.
If you are using a script tag or url to find a template, this step is done automatically by canJS.

So, if you want to render a template, stored in a variable, you have to do something like this:

```
var template = "< h1 ><%= title %> < / h1 >"; 
can.view.ejs('my-view-id', template);​​​​​​​
var rendered = can.view.render('my-view-id', data);
```

Now you have the document fragment in `rendered`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to jquery utils string format [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/StringFormat). There is an example that shows rendering html from template that was defined as as string.

Creating template:

```
$.tpl('tweet', [
    '<div id="tweet-{id:s}" class="tweet">',
        '<div class="tweet-body"><b>@{from:s}</b>: {body:s}',
            '(<a href="{href:s}" class="tweet-date">',
                '<abbr title="{timestamp:s}">{timesince:s}</abbr>',
            '</a>)',
        '</div>',
    '</div>'
]);
```

Rendering:

```
$.getJSON('/tweets/username/', function(resp, s){
    $.each(resp.tweets, function(idx, tweet) {
        $.tpl('tweet', {
            id: tweet.id,
            body: tweet.body,
            from: tweet.screen_name,
            timestamp: tweet.pub_time,
            timesince: $.timeago(tweet.pub_time)
        }).appendTo('#tweet-list');
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Because this can be a good alternative solution, but I want to use EJS templates, and render them with canjs. Thanks!